# Getting a new Fishing Rod

Tags: harvest-moon-two-towns

I just found out that there are some fish that you can only catch with the normal Fishing Rod. Considering I sold mine one season ago after I got the Master Rod, I freaked. Is there any way to get a new Fishing Rod or am I screwed?